# Power BI Distinct Count Incorrect Total

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate Distinct Count of `'Cust'` in `Table A` using DAX as

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('TableA'[Cust]))
```

Where I'm getting the distinct count correctly but the Total is Incorrect.

Any suggestions on correcting the formula would be helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: What total do you expect? It's possible that you have the same customer in multiple `BT` categories, in which case the total should not be the sum of the parts.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I'm expecting the total 232 yes Same Customers can be there for multiple BT's

Comment: So you want to double count those customers in your total? The current total only counts each customer once.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what is double count!! but since the sub totals as seen in the image is returning correct Distinct Count respective to BT.. hence i want the total of all subtotals as my grand total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have four customers `"Alex","John","Mike","Joe"` in three `BT` groups `AUT,CT,MT`.

`AUT` has `"Alex","John","Mike"`

`CT` has `"John","Joe"`

`MT` has `"Alex","John","Mike","Joe"`

Your table would be

```
BT   Count
----------
AUT  3
CT   2
MT   4
```

Now since you have only four total customers, I would expect your total to be `4`, not `3 + 2 + 4 = 9`. In the latter, you've double counted `Alex`, `Joe`, and `Mike` and triple counted `John`.

If you really do want your total to be the sum of the subtotals (though I don't see why you would want this in this case), you can do the following:

```
AddSubtotals = SUMX(VALUES('TableA'[BT]), CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('TableA'[CustomerName])))
```

This will give the weird `9` subtotal.

[image: Bad Subtotal]

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexis Olson!!

I got that.. Actual total is showing correct value (i.e. Count of Name) but where i was visualizing wrong.. thinking why the count of sub totals not matching with Grand Total.