# Wrong Total in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a measure, `Measure = divide(sum(amount),count(task))`, this is giving me incorrect total.

This is what I am getting in Power BI.

[image: Table]

Now the result which is expected here is

[image: Desired Result]

Basically what I want is to get the total of the measure that I have created, Power BI is dividing the total sum with the total count.

Comment: Related: [Distinct Count Incorrect Total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153766/power-bi-distinct-count-incorrect-total/54154526) and [DAX Average Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150526/dax-average-issue/49156948)

Comment: Can you explain your "correct total"? It makes no sense. How is it different from "Amount"?

Comment: Column Amount is a backend value and Column correct total is sum(total)/count(task), So if you see in the screen shot all the task has only one value, so the count will be 1.

Comment: In such case, Power BI total is correct. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Yes, as per functionality of the expression that i have written, it is correct, but the requirement is slightly different. I want to sum up the result which i am getting from sum(amount)/count(task)

Comment: Is their any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be quite mundane.
Instead of the `Measure = divide(sum(amount),count(task))` you may instead be wanting to use:

```
Measure = SUM(amount)
```

The `divide(sum(amount),count(task))` measure is a longhanded way of calculating the mean (`AVERAGE` being the shorthand way). But what you seem to require is the `SUM`.

Comment: Yes, i want to sum, but i want to sum up the values of the measure, what i am getting in Power BI is, it is dividing the total sum with count. if you see the second screenshot above, the column correct total is the expected result and the column wrong total is something that i am getting in Power BI. Do i need to change something in DAX

Comment: Is their any solution for this?

Comment: It's no longer clear whether you want the "correct total" to be the sum of the measure or the sum of the measure divided by the count of tasks, or something else. If you wanted the sum of the measure, change the Measure's DAX to my formula. If you wanted the sum divided by the count of tasks, then as @rado explains above, what you call the "Wrong total" is actually the right total. If you wanted something else, we would need to know more about where you're pulling the data from.